# LogCat not showing the command : Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

Following is code of onDraw function. It draws the circle and functions properly, but when I output circle coordinates in LOGCAT I don't see anything. I have imported the "android.Util.Log" as well,
Log.d command not showing in Logcat.

```
  @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);


    int pl = getPaddingLeft();
    int pr = getPaddingRight();
    int pt = getPaddingTop();
    int pb = getPaddingBottom();

    int usableWidth = w - (pl + pr);
    int usableHeight = h - (pt + pb);

    int radius = Math.min(usableWidth, usableHeight) / 2;
    int cx = pl + (usableWidth / 2);
    int cy = pt + (usableHeight / 2);

    paint.setColor(circleColor);
    //canvas.drawCircle(w, h, (radius * 1.5f), paint);
    Log.d("CIRCLE DRAW", "Circle coordinates are as ");//  +
            //"X: "+ w +
            //"Y: "+ h);

}
```

Comment: Check whether there is any filter applied for logcat window ?

Comment: Midhun, no filters. I am trying to show logcat in my Custom View Class's onDraw method. There aint any problem in that i assume.

Comment: Try a higher level of logging like info.

Comment: Please try to use lastest Android Studio version. One of my colleague tought me something like that.

Comment: Tuna , i am using latest version. Its showing other Logcat fine. but when i want to see coordinates in  onDraw() it doesn't give me desired result.

Comment: did you try to run `adb logcat` and watch the output?

Comment: pskink, Log.d is working fine in another(Main activity) of same Package.

Comment: ok so use the debugger and add the breakpoint in `onDraw` and see what happens

Comment: All variables in Custom View activity are not initialized. but log.d is taking constant string as parameter. It should behave good

Comment: trying using tag name without space characters. `logcat` has issues with properly filtering such tags